# how change part of url by preg_replace?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I am trying to change all the links of a html with php preg_replace. All the uris have the following form

```
test.com/item/16
```

I want to change it to:

```
test.com/z/item/16
```

I tried the following, but it returns no changes:

```
$links = 'http://test.com/item/16';
preg_replace("/item","z/item",$links);

echo $links; 
// output >>> http://test.com/z/item/16
```

Comment: Your regex is missing delimeters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need delimiter and return of preg_replace set to variable

```
$links = 'http://test.com/item/16';
$links = preg_replace('/\/item/','/z/item',$links);

echo $links;
```

But, why don't you use just str_replace in this case?

Comment: I think for replacing /item/ to /z/item/ you don't need regex. But if this is more complex problem and just simple question, use regex. :-).

If you ask for my code, there is delimiter ( / ) on start and end of regex and more important change is adding $links = preg_replace(...

Answer (score 3):

You have to use delimiters as @nickb has pointed out, *i.e.* `/your_regular_expression/`. The `/` is the standard delimiter for regular expressions, and so, it being a special character, you'd have to escape the `/` you want to match by using a backslash, `\/`:

```
preg_replace("/\/item/","z/item",$links);
```

But luckily, you can choose your own delimiters, like `#`, so then no need to escape the `/`:

```
preg_replace("#/item#","z/item",$links);
```

Comment: I used the second solution for paths, it works like charm. thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<?php
$links = 'http://test.com/item/16';
$a = preg_replace("/item/","z/item",$links);

echo $a;
```

preg_replace does not change the input string but instead returns a modified string....which is stored in $a variable..

Comment: Pritesh has a good point too—you need to store the return value. +1, I missed that.

Comment: thnx Andrew for appreciation..and Masi.dr if it is fixed than you can accept the answer also...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the provided answers is that if you have more than one instance of /item in the URL, all of them will get replaced, for example a URL like:

```
http://items.domain.com/item/16
```

would get messed up, try modifying just the path:

```
$path = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_PATH );
$url  = str_replace( $path, '/z'.$path, $url );
```